# Showing that the surface $z = 3x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2$ lies entirely above every one of its tangent planes

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The hint given is to look at the Taylor expansion at every point in space.

It's not immediately clear to me how to proceed with this. If I calculate out the equation of the tangent plane at a point $(x,y,z) = (a,b,c)$ with
$$\nabla F(a,b,c) \cdot ((x,y,z) - (a,b,c)) = 0$$
where $F(x,y,z) = 3x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2 - z$ and I substitute in $c = 3a^2 - 2ab - 2b^2$, I get a very nasty equation.

I can also calculate the Taylor expansion of $f(x,y) = 3x^2 - 2xy + 2y^2$, which to the second degree or above is just that polynomial itself, and I don't really see how that helps.